# Im getting error Comparison arguments must be compatible types: String, NULL

Tags: apex, batch

```
global class Trainerverificationupdate implements Database.Batchable<sObject> {
   
    global Database.QueryLocator start(Database.BatchableContext BC) {
        
        String query = 'SELECT Id,LinkedIn_Profile__c,Verification_Status__c,Background_Check__c FROM Trainer_Master__C';
        return Database.getQueryLocator(query);
    }
    
    global void execute(Database.BatchableContext BC, List<Trainer_Master__c> scope) {
        
        for(Trainer_Master__c Tcc : scope)
        {        
            if(Tcc.LinkedIn_Profile__c == null){
                Tcc.Verification_Status__c='Details Needed';
              System.debug('Details Needed');
            }
            else if(Tcc.LinkedIn_Profile__c !==null && Tcc.Background_Check__c == false){
                Tcc.Verification_Status__c='Non Verified';
                 System.debug('Non Verified');
            }else if(Tcc.LinkedIn_Profile__c !==null && Tcc.Background_Check__c == true){
                Tcc.Verification_Status__c='Verified';
                 System.debug('Verified');
            }
        }
        update scope;
    }   
    
    global void finish(Database.BatchableContext BC) {
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**tl;dr:** you wanted to use `!=` instead of `!==`.

---

`!==` is used for strict inequality checks.

You can use it for things like:

```
Account a = new Account();
Account b = new Account();
System.assert(a!==b);
```

Which means that if you modify a, it will also not modify b, whereas:

```
Account a = new Account();
Account b = a;
System.assert(a===b);
```

Would inform us that modifying a would also modify b:

```
Account a = new Account();
Account b = a;
b.Name = 'Hello';
System.assert(a.Name == b.Name);
```

This is usually pretty limited in Apex, since we rarely care about such equality.

The error here tells us that we can't do a strict equality or strict inequality check across different types, since it is never possible for them to be strictly equal, and always not strictly equal, so the code should not check this kind of equality.

For example:

```
Account a = new Account();
Contact b = new Contact();
System.assert(a === b);
```

Will not compile because of this obvious conclusion. `null` is a special type, as it is in most languages, so you cannot strictly compare null to anything else.

Most of the time, you don't need this type of check, so instead you'll want to use `==` for equality checks, and `!=` for inequality checks.

- `==` means "compare values for equality"
- `!=` means "compare values for inequality"
- `===` means "are the two objects the same object"
- `!==` means "are the two objects different objects"

Comment: Thank you sir solved the error I was wrong at the equality check symbol

Comment: I believe you inverted your `tl;dr`?

Comment: @AdrianLarson So I did. Nice catch.

Comment: It had me super confused why you would need to use strict comparison. 